# Extract values of a dataframe according to values of a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, merge, match, extract

I am trying to design a color palette with gradient colors matching values of a numeric variable with R.

I have a vector of values similar to this one. There are negative values, repeating values and missing values.

```
vec <- c(-1.17, -1.12, 0, 0.01, 0.01, NA, 0.01, -1.17, 1.2, 1.21, 1.35, 1.35, NA, NA)
```

I am designing the color palette with gradient colors as follows:

```
colnum <- seq(-1.5, 1.5, 0.01) # to define range of values
library(colorspace) 
color <- diverge_hcl(length(colnum))[rank(colnum)]  # the color pallette going from blue to red
```

Now, I am really stuck at the last step. How to extract a matrix where I know which value is assigned to which color?

Here is what I am trying:

```
values <- data.frame(unique(vec))
colnames(values) <- "colnum"

colpal <- data.frame(colnum, color)

colpal2 <- merge(values, colpal, by="colnum", all.x=TRUE)
colpal2

 colnum   color
1  -1.17 #6270AF
2  -1.12 #6B77B2
3   0.00 #E2E2E2
4   0.01    <NA>
5   1.20    <NA>
6   1.21 #AA5367
7   1.35 #9D3752
8     NA    <NA>
```

Why am I not getting the color values for 0.01 and 1.20 when they are among the unique values?

```
unique(vec)
[1] -1.17 -1.12  0.00  0.01    NA  1.20  1.21  1.35
```

Edit: I also just tried this option and I get the same result.

```
colpal[colpal$colnum %in% unique(vec), ]

     colnum   color
34   -1.17 #6270AF
39   -1.12 #6B77B2
151   0.00 #E2E2E2
272   1.21 #AA5367
286   1.35 #9D3752
```

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is a simple `as.character`.

```
colpal[colpal$colnum %in% as.character(unique(vec)), ]
```